# Javascript Return Variable across Different Files

Tags: javascript, voice-recognition

I am trying to build a web app that allows users to call each other. Currently, I am trying to implement a voice recognition feature that does the following:

> The voice recognition starts when the call is connected. It recognizes
> and constantly populates a variable with the recognized text as the call progresses. When the call is terminated, return the variable
> containing the final transcribed text.

In one of my HTML files, I am calling two JS files in the following order:

```
  <script src="/resource/js/chat/call.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/resource/js/chat/voice_recognition.js" defer></script>
```

In `voice_recognition.js`, I have a voice recognition function that translates what a user speaks into text, and populates the text into the variable.

```
function start_transcript(variable_to_populate) {
  var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        variable_to_populate += event.results[i][0].transcript;               
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the `call.js` function, I am using an API that could detect when a call is initiated and disconnected. I have the following codes inside `call.js`

```
var final_transcript = "";
device.on("connect", function(conn) {
  start_transcript(final_transcript);
})

device.on("disconnect", function(conn) {
  console.log(final_transcript);
})
```

But the `final_transcript` logged empty after call terminates even though there has been voice recognition going on. Is there anything wrong with my approach of declaring a global variable called `final_transcript` and passing to the `voice_recognition` function to populate the variable? Also, is there a better approach you can think of to solve this problem?

Comment: `variable_to_populate += ` always only modifies the local variable that your parameter `variable_to_populate` declared. The `final_transcript` is not passed by reference, it is never reassigned. You might try passing an array and mutating that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the order in which you load the files first.
`call.js` is dependant on the `start_transcript` function in the other file. Which is undefined atm.

```
  <script src="/resource/js/chat/voice_recognition.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/resource/js/chat/call.js" defer></script>
```

*edit

Also change `.on` to => `.onresult`. Tested in my browser and does not seem to be an 'on'-method.

```
device.onresult("connect", function(conn) {
  start_transcript(final_transcript);
})

device.onresult("disconnect", function(conn) {
  console.log(final_transcript);
})
```

Comment: Just tried, still empty

Comment: And is `recognition` even started?
Need to call`recognition.start()`. `device` and `recognition` are two different variables.